# Rails asset pipeline - image_path helper only working in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have a problem with asset preocompilation in Rails (3.2.7).

I am including an favicon like this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<%= image_path("favicon.png") %>" />
```

On development mode I set `config.assets.compile = true`. There everything works fine, the rendered HTML looks like this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/favicon.png" />
```

But on production, where I set `config.assets.compile = false`, I get the error

```
Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError in Home#index
...
favicon.png isn't precompiled
```

I already ran `rake assets:precompile` and i can clearly see, that the asset is available under `public/assets/favicon.png`.

I know, that i could set `config.assets.compile = true` in production, but i don´t want to do that (because of performance reasons).

Has anyone an idea, why my rails app is not able to resolve the correct path to the asset in production? Thanks!

---

Update:
maybe also useful to know: It happens not only for images, also for other assets.

For example `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "screen", :media => "all" %>` also produces the error `screen.css isn't precompiled` when config.assets.compile is set to false.

Comment: I'm using the public folder for images, cause it doesn't work for me in any environment.

Answer (score 1):

You must tell Rails which assets are to be precompiled. You do this in `config/application.rb` or `config/environments/production.rb` with the [`config.assets.precompile` config key](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets).

Rails starts with a default list of assets to precompile, including `["application.js", "application.css"]`, but if you want your own assets to be precompiled too, you have to add them to the list.

For example:

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # other config ...

    config.assets.precompile += ["screen.css", "*.png"]
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I already have the additional assets configured in my application.rb: `config.assets.precompile += ["admin.css", "screen.css", "static.css", "*.png"]`. All the required files are also listed in the manifest.yml and are available in the `/public/assets` folder

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a couple of tries I figured out, how to fix this. Nevertheless it´s a little bit strange and does not satisfy me completely. It only worked for me, when I set `digest` to true and provide the path to the `manifest`:

```
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.manifest = Rails.root.join("public/assets")
```

It would be interesting to know, what´s behind this "logic".