# rails image_path issue in prod, no custom domain, no thumbprint, bad path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

This is a rails 3.2.13 app.

I'm very confused what's the issue here. Any help is much appreciated.
I have my image at this location:

```
app/assets/images/icons/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
```

This is in the layout.html.erb:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<%= image_path("icons/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png") %>" />
```

In dev it links correctly:

```
<link ... href="/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" />
```

In production

```
it does not link correctly:
<link ... href="/icons/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" />
what i am expecting:    
<link ... href="http://asset.domain.com/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-precomposed-5796a048f16a314924adbb237adf88d6.png" />
```

When I browse the production server, I see the thumbprinted image in the correct location:

```
public/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-precomposed-5796a048f16a314924adbb237adf88d6.png
```

Here is my `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
Aliencom::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://asset.domain.com'

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)

  config.assets.precompile += ['head.js']
  config.assets.precompile += ['libs/respond.src.js']
  config.assets.precompile += ['libs/jquery-1.10.2.js']
  config.assets.precompile += ['libs/swfobject.js']
  config.assets.precompile += ['libs/greensock/TweenMax.min.js']
  config.assets.precompile += ['libs/greensock/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js']

  # Add the fonts and swfs path
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'swfs')

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5



  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.update({
       #:url => "i/:class/:attachment/:basename_:style_:hash.:extension",
       # :url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:basename.:extension",
       #:url => "/system/v2/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:created_at.:extension",
       :use_timestamp => false,
       :url => "//assets.staging.aliencom.net/system/v3/:class_:attachment/:id/:basename_:style.:extension",
       :path => ":rails_root/public/system/v3/:class_:attachment/:id/:basename_:style.:extension",
       :hash_secret => "P/IbDQ4t2qYNLCKyVREvRhyRPWYHn3CW3fAsIGYsnAa3OfWBJeIE91gW9ZyLWZPBW+TlqI278yLtGA7BIZB+DTR9Bp9J0usbFMn7mCh1aLAn2WKzZYrrJZ0QcFL5TEkYhDISKymd34bwS0x2zOhdzeKaSkQn9iXidvQ++Pt0YBg="
   })

end
```

This is from the capistrano (capistrano 3) deploy task

```
...
INFO [231ef199] Running ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile on 97.107.134.133
DEBUG [231ef199] Command: cd /var/www/ac_staging/releases/20140226162225 && ( RBENV_ROOT=~/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=1.9.3-p448 RAILS_ENV=staging ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [231ef199]    /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby /var/www/ac_staging/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
INFO [231ef199] Finished in 95.166 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
...
```

Comment: are you running `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: What link is it pointing to now in prod? right click and see the url. Yes assets need to be precompiled in prod mode for them to be found. I think they are though, based on the link you posted.

Comment: @Slicedpan I've posted my capistrano output, i think that is the right lines.

Comment: @isaffie the production path output is included above.

Comment: @LessQuesar try converting <link ... /> erb/haml(whatever you are using)

Answer (score 0):

In production my experience has files loading from the PUBLIC directory not compiled.
Try putting the image in your PUBLIC directory with the appropriate folders with the file name intact.

So for `/icons/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png` put it in `/public/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png` Try puting in non compiled image.

Comment: Yes this does work. Its mainly frustrating that I can't figure out how to use image_path correctly for thumbprint/custom domain etc. CSS and JS are linking fine.

Comment: This is a common issue. I have one application using the same code as another and one will use the compiled image while the other yells for the original. I have yet to discover why.

Comment: and a bit like magic, i got it working. I hacked a bunch of settings like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368037/rails-asset-pipeline-image-path-helper-only-working-in-development and more, not sure what made a difference. But i guess i'm closing this one.